# How to get the current guard by current route in a Multiple Authentication Laravel app?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I'd like to get the current guard by the current route. I don't want to know if a user is authenticated with a guard a specific guard.

Comment: what makes a guard the 'current' guard in this scenario?

Comment: the controller designated by the route makes set the current guard. I'd like to get the current guard in Blade scope

Comment: and you are doing that via the 'auth' middleware?

Comment: the middleware is set to auth:admin in the controller's constructor

Comment: You can change the current using guard to what you want with `Auth::shouldUse('admin');` then whenever you call `Auth::guard()` it will return admin instead of default guard

Answer (score 5):

If you want an instance of the actual guard:

```
Auth::guard(); // calls to what is currently set as default
```

If you want the name of the driver/guard:

```
Auth::getDefaultDriver(); // name of the current default
```

The default guard is set via configuration. The `auth` middleware also sets the default guard when it runs. If the middleware was set as `auth:admin` and the user authenticates, you can get to the route, the default guard will now be `admin`.

Comment: `Auth::getDefaultDriver()` just returns the value of `config('auth.defaults.guard')` which is the default, not the one currently in use.

Comment: @miken32 the `auth` middleware calls `shouldUse` which sets the default guard by calling `setDefaultDriver`, which then sets that config value ... current guard means the one that the `auth` middleware used to authenticate ... so that value is always the current default guard ... you missed the last sentence of the answer that explains the result of this as this config value is not static

Comment: Makes sense. I ended up using a different method but should have known better than to doubt you!

Comment: @miken32 it does this so you can pass multiple guards as parameters, that way which ever one authenticates the user becomes your default, as it would be unrealistic to have to hard code multiple guards everywhere you interact with the auth system after authentication has actually happened  ... do you use a multi-auth system with different models?

Comment: @miken32 i would love to hear what solution you came up with, i bet it is pretty clever ... hit up my contact page on my site